# Loopback JS: send email to different hosts

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, loopbackjs, nodemailer

This is my defined email datasource.

```
 "email": {
"name": "email",
"connector": "mail",
"transports": [
   {
    "type": "SMTP",
    "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "secure": true,
    "port": 465,
    "auth": {
      "user": "${ADMIN_EMAIL}",
      "pass": "${ADMIN_PASS}"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

When sending email, it is only working for gmail emails. Could any one tell me why it would not work when sending email to other type of emails.

It is actually working using nodemailer.

Comment: you mean that email is not received by the recipient or you want to send it with a different method, like from yahoo or something?

Comment: My sender is a GMAIL email. But It is not received by the reciepent which is a non-GMAIL account

Comment: do you get any send report or failure report to your gmail inbox? or maybe the message is in the spam? how many emails are you sending at once, maybe it's spooling issue or so?

Comment: I got a failure report which is gmail's security alert, because I was trying to log in from a remote server. It works fine now after I allowed logging in from that server.